# clip-path stops working when adding div inside of clipped div

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I'm working on a project right now where I'm trying to have a `div` at the bottom of a `div`. I did that okay but I also wanted have the sides of the `div` angled. I was also able to do that okay. I started adding the stuff I wanted in the `div` (the one at the bottom and with angled sides) and had already added one `div` but when I added another one (with not much difference between the two) the `clip-path` stopped working! I'm using HTML and CSS (no bootstrap).

**Here is my Code (https://jsfiddle.net/MalMan35/uu7weo6o/4/):**

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.messegeHolder {
  top: 50%;  
  -webkit-transform: translate(-285px, -185px);
  transform: translate(-285px, -185px);
  left: 50%; 
  width: 570px;
  height: 370px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.mainbox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(51,51,51,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 90%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(51,51,51,1)), color-stop(45%, rgba(51,51,51,1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(17,17,17,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 90%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 90%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 90%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(51,51,51,1) 0%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 45%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 90%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 100%);
  border-radius: 50px;  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 50px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #999999;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.metalLine {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  left: 55px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 51px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  background: grey;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 50px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 50px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 50px #000000;
}
.squareSpeaker{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 6px;
  left: 173px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #3e3e3e;
  background: #747474; /* Old browsers */
  background: url('http://www.z.minksfamily.com/squareSpeaker.png') center, -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #747474 1%, #747474 1%, #5d5d5d 86%);
  background: url('http://www.z.minksfamily.com/squareSpeaker.png') center, -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #747474 1%,#747474 1%,#5d5d5d 86%);
  background: url('http://www.z.minksfamily.com/squareSpeaker.png') center, radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #747474 1%,#747474 1%,#5d5d5d 86%); 
  -webkit-animation: squareNoise 5s linear 0s 2;
  animation: squareNoise 5s linear 0s 2;
}
@-webkit-keyframes squareNoise {
  0%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
  1%  {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  10%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
  11% {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  30%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
  31%  {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  40%   {background-size: 100px 35px;} 
  41%  {background-size: 105px 40px;} 
  50%   {background-size: 100px 35px;} 
  51%  {background-size: 105px 40px;} 
  60%   {background-size: 100px 35px;} 
  61%  {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  80%   {background-size: 100px 35px;} 
  81%  {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  90%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
  91%  {background-size: 105px 40px;} 
  100%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}  
}
@keyframes squareNoise {
  0%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
  1%  {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  10%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
  11% {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  30%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
  31%  {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  40%   {background-size: 100px 35px;} 
  41%  {background-size: 105px 40px;} 
  50%   {background-size: 100px 35px;} 
  51%  {background-size: 105px 40px;} 
  60%   {background-size: 100px 35px;} 
  61%  {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  80%   {background-size: 100px 35px;} 
  81%  {background-size: 105px 40px;}
  90%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
  91%  {background-size: 105px 40px;} 
  100%   {background-size: 100px 35px;}
}
.reloadHolder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 74px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="messegeHolder">
  <div class="mainbox">
    <div class="metalLine">
      <div class="squareSpeaker"></div>
      <div class="reloadHolder"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean, the white rectangle? http://i.stack.imgur.com/oTBvO.png

Comment: Yes that is the second div. Strange, I just tested it in chrome on mac and it worked okay! I was originally testing it using Chromium 45 on linux. How can I make sure it works on all browsers?

Comment: You can try with tool like https://crossbrowsertesting.com/

Comment: I tried the free trial and tested it in Chrome 45 and it was the same problem. But that still doesn't tell me how to fix it. BTW The chome that I'm testing in (the one on the mac) is Chrome 49